# Does Java support Mulitiple Inheritance?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

From the Java fact that all class in Java have a parent class as `Object`. But the same Java says that it doesn't support multiple inheritance. But what this code mean ?

```
public class A extends B
{
          //Blah blah blah
}
```

From the above code it means that Class `A` extends Class `B`. Now Class `A` also have inherited the properties of `Object` class which is the super class of `B`. Is this doesn't mean that Class `A` have inherited both Class `B` and `Object` Class, this what we called Multiple inheritance right?

So now Java supports **Multiple inheritance**, if not then what is the answer for the above code(which shows multiple inheritance)

Comment: What you have could be called **multi-level inheritance**, which is a different thing.

Comment: multi-level single inheritance, maybe ?

Answer (score 9):

No, this is single inheritance. A inherits from B, B inherits from Object.

Multiple inheritance would be `A` extends from `B` and `C`, where `B` and `C` don't inherit from each other, which can cause the [Diamond Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem):

If `B` defines a method `foo()` and `C` also defines a method `foo()`, and I do this:

```
new A().foo();
```

Which `foo()` implementation will be used?

This is a huge problem in many languages, so the Java designers decided not to allow multiple inheritance.

Comment: Java does support "multiple interface inheritance". You can have: `interface Foobar extends Foo, Bar`.

Comment: @Martinho I know, I left that for someone else :-)

Answer (score 2):

Multiple inheritance is having more than 1 direct base class. The example you have given is single inheritance.

For example, if you have 3 classes `A`, `B` and `C`...

```
public class A extends B
```

with

```
public class B extends C
```

is still just single inheritance.
Multiple inheritance would be

```
public class A extends B, C
```

Answer (score 1):

Java does not support Multiple Inheritance by a developer. Behind the scenes, the compiler ensures everything extends Object.

Basically, the compiler will modify

public Class A extends Object, B to practically be Class A extends B and Class B extends Object.

Comment: Really? The compiler does this? This would mean MI is supported by the JVM but not the language, right? I found that doubtful as the JVM was built specifically to run Java.

Comment: I'm not sure how what I described is MI in the JVM? I'm making assumptions here, as I don't know the implementation of the compiler, but my understanding would be that the compiler would look at the hierarchy of your class, and effectively add an 'extends Object' to the last superclass in the hierarchy. It may not be implemented like that, but that's the effect. No MI in the JVM here.

Comment: (Ok, I got confused by the `public class A extends Object, B` part. That doesn't compile right?) I think the algorithm can be very simple: just slap `extends Object` to classes without `extends`. No need to visit hierarchies.

Comment: I think that compiler adds extends Object but IFF there is nothing which the class extends directly by specifying it via the extends keyword

Answer (score 1):

Multiple inheritance means that one class **extends** two other classes. Multiple inheritance is allowed in e.g. C++. But this is not that same as:

```
class Object {
...
}

class B extends Object { //default, not need to be there
...
}

class A extends B {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> From the Java fact that all class in Java have a parent class as Object

Actually no, that's not true. `Object` is only the **default** parent class. If you explicitly specify a parent, as in your example (`A extends B`), then the class you're defining no longer has `Object` as an immediate parent.

However, the fact that `Object` is the default means that it's impossible to create a class (except for `Object` itself) without a superclass. Since every class must have a superclass, every class has to have `Object` as an *ancestor* at some level.

Comment: With special rules for `Object` itself, of course. `Object` is just magic.

Comment: @Anto: I was trying to say `Object` is the only class that can exist without a superclass. Somehow I missed "(except for `Object` itself)" in David's answer.